# Can i somehow access data in my android's desktop?

Tags: android

Very beginner (havent really started yet) in Java Android, my question is simple: Can i access data in android homescreen with an app or widget or command line? I need to all apps that are in desktop. How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are hundreds, if not thousands, of home screen implementations, across the ~2 billion Android devices that are in use. None have to offer an API for you to use. None have to have the concept of a "desktop" with shortcuts and wallpaper and such, either.

You are welcome to write your own home screen, in which case you could provide an API for others to use that supplies this data.

Comment: Marked as an answer. Then i need to make my own sadly :c